# Apache2.4 precedence of _default_:443 over first *:443 virtualhost definition

Tags: apache, virtualhost, apache2.4

I'm running Apache 2.4.6 on a development server, which has been happily hosting a number of `VirtualHost` sites (*:443), on a number of dev servers for quite some time, the main one (which happened to be alphabetically the first) we'll call `<mainsite>.net` (the servers it runs on don't match `ServerName` so `<servername>.net` will always pick up the default Virtualhost at `<servername>`, which should be `<mainsite>`

I recently added a variance of the main site, `ServerAlias *.<mainsite>` where the conf.d file is `<mainsite>-wild.conf` and everything stopped working.

The issue seems to come down to the precedence of `<VirtualHost *:443 _default_:443>` which is in my `<mainsite>.conf` against `<VirtualHost *:443>` in `<mainsite>-wild.conf`.  Apparently `<mainsite>-wild.conf` comes before `<mainsite>.conf` when loading `conf.d`.

I've managed to debug the issue by using `apachectl -S` to identify which site has the 'default' flag, and strangely it isn't necessarily the one with `_default_` in it, its the one that comes first in the conf.d folder, which threw me somewhat (if `_default_` is ignored, what is it for).

What I've concluded is that I can bypass the problem by renaming `<mainsite>.conf` to `00-<mainsite>.conf` but what I want to know is why is Apache ignoring `_default_`?  is it simply because its *:443?  I thought in the post SNI days that wasn't a problem anymore, which beggars the question, is this a bug in apache?

I searched online and found no discussion on precedence involving Apache 2.4 (when the Listen/NameVirtualHost setup changed) or after SNI (before which you couldn't really do VirtualHost on :443, unless they all shared a certificate), so thought I'd ask StackOverflow.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In Apache 2.4 `<VirtualHost>` directive, the string `_default_` is an alias for `*`.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#virtualhost